# Computed observable arrayIndexOf

Tags: knockout.js

Anybody know how to make arrayIndexOf work below? I want the computed observable to return the `index + ". " + Name` of each array item. e.g. `1. Item one`. Right now it returns `-1. Item one`

```
self.Tweet = ko.computed(function () {
    var items = self.Items().map(function (elem) {
        return ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(elem.Name()) + ". " + elem.Name();
    return items;
}, self);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the ko.utils.arrayIndexOf function in wrong way. `ko.utils.arrayIndexOf( Array , Object )`

```
self.computedObject=ko.computed(function(){
    var items=self.colors().map(function(elem){
        return ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.colors(),elem)+1+"."+elem.color;
    });
    console.log(items);
    return items;
},self);
```

[Here is sample in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vaez/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got my arrayIndexOf to work

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.suggestions = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.filterText = ko.observable('');

  self.filterText.subscribe(function(newValue) {});

  self.suggestionsFilter = ko.computed(function() {
    
    if (self.filterText() === '') {
      return self.suggestions();
    } else {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.suggestions(), function(item) {

        var filterResults = item.option.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filterText().toLowerCase()) == 0;
        return filterResults;

      });
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 postcode-search" id="js-postcode-search-suggestions">
  <input id="name-search" class="form-control" type="search" name="postcode" minlength="1" placeholder="Postcode or Address" data-bind="textInput: filterText" />
  <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="visible: suggestions().length > 1" style="display: none">
    <ul class="suggestions" data-bind="foreach: suggestionsFilter">
      <li class="pad-top-bottom">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="option" data-bind="html: option"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```